# Не отображается веб приложение на VueJS в telegram

Tags: vue.js, telegram

Пытаюсь интегрировать веб приложение в телеграм. Приложение написано на VueJS. В браузере все корректно отображается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в телеграмме видно только первую надпись:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первая надпись написана в корневом файле index.html:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А остальные уже .vue файлах:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так происходит на десктопном клиенте телеграмма, в мобильном приложении все также корректно отображается.